# How to convert days on a calendar when click into a string

Tags: c#

Here is my code. I was trying to test the ***SelectedDate*** for my program so the user can click on the date and it'll make it into a string. However, when the ***SelectedDate*** tag has a red line under it that is indicating that:

> 'monthCalendar1' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedDate' and no accessible extension method 'SeclectedDate' accepted a first argument of type 'monthCalendar' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

```
private void monthCalendar1_SelectedDate(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    txtDay.Text = monthCalendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd");
}
```

[[image]]

Comment: Note that the `visual-studio` tag should only be used for questions pertaining to the Visual Studio application, and not for code that you write using it. You can click on any tag and see information about it (or its usage).

Comment: "...has an error..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: If you refer to the [docs for MonthCalendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar?view=netframework-4.7.2#properties) you can see that it does not have a `SelectedDate` property.

Comment: @JohnB I edited my question if that will help you better understand. I also did debug. I'm trying to allow the users to click on the date they want to make an event; however,  the _**SelectedDate**_ property isnt working (I wrote out the error i get in the post)

Comment: @John How will i be able to grab an selected date and convert it into a string

Comment: @John Any date the user clicks on. I'm going to add a image of my program if that will help

Comment: @John I'm sorry for all the trouble I'm new at this. Anyway, as you can see the user will be able to select any date they want and the program will convert it into a string.

Comment: If they can only select a single date, then replacing your `txtDay.Text = monthCalendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd");` with the second option in Vijunav's answer will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use it like this:

```
var selectedDate = (DateTime.Parse(e.Start.ToShortDateString())).Day;
```

or

```
txtDay.Text = (DateTime.Parse(e.Start.ToShortDateString())).Day.ToString();
```

Comment: Will this be within the function. Remember I'm using visual studios so this is to allow the calendar to be clickable and then it'll grab the selected date and store it in a string